# CentOS is asking for ubuntu login

Tags: ubuntu, centos, login

I've just installed CentOS 7 and booted for the first time. I'm greeted with the prompt:

```
CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
Kernel 3.10.0-229.el7._x86-64 on an x86_64

ubuntu login:
```

The login password for "root" I specified during installation doesn't work. I didn't add any other users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ubuntu` seems to be your hostname, you should be able to login by typing first the user name of the user you want to use to login , and then the password

Once you login, you should change your hostname and choose one more 
outstanding

Comment: @101 , you can also reset root password , the steps are described here : http://sharadchhetri.com/2014/10/11/centos-7-rhel-7-reset-recover-forgotten-root-password/